# Launching WPF Window from F# interactive, keyboard input broken

Tags: c#, wpf, f#, fsi

A GUI was developed in WPF, and when launching it as a standalone application, all editable fields (datagrid columns, textboxes, etc.) work fine.

However, when instantiating the window from FSI, no individual key characters are registered when typing.  The interesting thing is copy/paste and highlight + delete all work.

The window is being initialized like this:

```
public void ShowGui()
{
    guiWindow = new MainWindow(Bench, this);
    guiWindow.Show();
    guiWindow.Activate();     
}
```

this function is then being invoked in FSI

All other functionality seems to work (button clicks, switching tabs), but any element that takes key input will not register the typed characters.

Comment: [`Application().Run(guiWindow)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597011(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, as there is no Application instance since it's running from FSI.  It did get me going down the right path though, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? @ildjarn 's solution is blocking.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what I followed: http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/